# Cleaning up StateListDrawables

Tags: android, garbage-collection, imageview, out-of-memory

I am creating an android application that dynamically downloads images from the internet and then places them onto an `ImageView`, allowing the user to set a default image and a highlighted image. To do this I download the data and save it to a file, from there whenever the image is needed I create a `BitmapDrawable` from the file and place it in a `StateListDrawable`. When the `ImageView` is no longer needed what is the correct way to dispose of the `StateListDrawable` so I don't leak memory and they get garbage collected? Should I hold references to each `BitmapDrawable` in the `StateListDrawable` so I can call recycle on them? What about setting the `StateListDrawable` callbacks to null? Or is setting the `ImageView` to null enough to not leak memory?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm interested in this too. Found a way?

Comment: Some code will help.. bitmap loading and setting code.

Comment: I think the issue is clear. You have a button or some view that holds several bitmaps in a StateListDrawable and you want to recycle them when you're done with it. Currently I have a "Bitmap" cleaner class that I pass bitmaps too (including their context). Upon onDestroy, I call the Bitmap cleaner with the context and it will recycle all bitmaps associated with that context. This works quite well. Just wondering if there's a better solution.

Answer (score 2):

The Java VM will automatically take care of collecting your unwanted `StateListDrawable`s.  All you have to do is make sure there is no way the `StateListDrawable` itself can be referenced from your program, either by reassigning the references to another `Object`, or by setting the references to `null`.  It does not even matter if the `StateListDrawable` still holds references to other objects you DO want to keep (such as the callbacks you discussed)...once an `Object` cannot be referenced, it is eligible for garbage collection.  When the VM deems it a good time to free up memory, it will take care of deleting the `StateListDrawable`s for you, you do not need to worry about calling `recycle()` on any of your objects yourself.

A simple way to see this if you are editing using Eclipse is to view the LogCat messages while your program is running in the emulator.  There will occasionally be messages saying: "GC freed xxx objects / xxx bytes in xxx ms."

From the [Java tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/usingobject.html):

> "Some object-oriented languages require that you keep track of all the
>   objects you create and that you explicitly destroy them when they are
>   no longer needed. The Java platform allows you to create as many
>   objects as you want (limited, of course, by what your system can
>   handle), and you don't have to worry about destroying them. The Java
>   runtime environment deletes objects when it determines that they are
>   no longer being used. This process is called garbage collection.
>
> An object is eligible for garbage collection when there are no more
>   references to that object. References that are held in a variable are
>   usually dropped when the variable goes out of scope. Or, you can
>   explicitly drop an object reference by setting the variable to the
>   special value null. Remember that a program can have multiple
>   references to the same object; all references to an object must be
>   dropped before the object is eligible for garbage collection."

Edit: From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html) for 'Bitmap.recycle()`,

> "Free the native object associated with this bitmap, and clear the
>   reference to the pixel data...This is an advanced call, and normally
>   need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this
>   memory when there are no more references to this bitmap."